# Waiting for all Queued Backgroundworkers to finish?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, .net-4.0

I was trying out some `QueuedBackgroundWorker` class that I found [here](http://pooyakhamooshi.blogspot.com/2009/11/create-thread-safe-queued.html).  It works well, except I'm wondering how I can wait till all queued workers have finished?  For example, if the user goes to close the program I'd like the program to wait until all workers are finished and then close.

I tried doing something like this on the GUI thread, but it just seems to block:

```
        try
        {
            while (myWorkerQueue.Queue.Count > 0) ;

        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {

        }
```

Also tried `while(myWorkerQueue.Queue.Peek() != null)` and got same result.

Code for `QueuedBackgroundWorker`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel;

/// <summary>
/// This is thread-safe
/// </summary>
public class QueuedBackgroundWorker
{
    #region Constructors

        public QueuedBackgroundWorker() { }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    Queue<object> Queue = new Queue<object>();

    object lockingObject1 = new object();

    public delegate void WorkerCompletedDelegate<K>(K result, Exception error);

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// doWork is a method with one argument
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">is the type of the input parameter</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="K">is the type of the output result</typeparam>
    /// <param name="inputArgument"></param>
    /// <param name="doWork"></param>
    /// <param name="workerCompleted"></param>
    public void RunAsync<T,K>(Func<T, K> doWork, T inputArgument, WorkerCompletedDelegate<K> workerCompleted)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = GetBackgroundWorker<T,K>(doWork, workerCompleted);

        Queue.Enqueue(new QueueItem(bw, inputArgument));

        lock (lockingObject1)
        {
            if (Queue.Count == 1)
            {
                ((QueueItem)this.Queue.Peek()).RunWorkerAsync();      
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use this method if you don't need to handle when the worker is completed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="doWork"></param>
    /// <param name="inputArgument"></param>
    public void RunAsync<T,K>(Func<T, K> doWork, T inputArgument)
    {
        RunAsync(doWork, inputArgument, null);
    }

    private BackgroundWorker GetBackgroundWorker<T, K>(Func<T, K> doWork, WorkerCompletedDelegate<K> workerCompleted)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = false;
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;

        bw.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (doWork != null)
            {
                args.Result = (K)doWork((T)args.Argument);
            }
        };

        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (workerCompleted != null)
            {
                workerCompleted((K)args.Result, args.Error);
            }
            Queue.Dequeue();
            lock (lockingObject1)
            {
                if (Queue.Count > 0)
                {
                    ((QueueItem)this.Queue.Peek()).RunWorkerAsync();                  
                }
            }
        };
        return bw;
    }

    #endregion
}

public class QueueItem
{
    #region Constructors

    public QueueItem(BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker, object argument)
    {
        this.BackgroundWorker = backgroundWorker;
        this.Argument = argument;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public object Argument { get; private set; }

    public BackgroundWorker BackgroundWorker { get; private set; }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public void RunWorkerAsync()
    {
        this.BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(this.Argument);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Putting the UI thread into a "while" loop like you show above is a really bad idea because now the UI thread can no longer do any UI work (in simple terms). How long are your background threads? Are any of them using Invoke or BeginInvoke to make UI updates. A better solution will depend somewhat on what your background threads are doing.

Comment: They are doing some background calculations and database reads/saves with the results.  Each worker is usually under a few minutes.

Comment: What do you mean by "waiting" ? if you run the while (myWorkerQueue.Queue.Count > 0) ; on the UI thread and it is blocking then you are waiting

Comment: I think it's deadlocking.. in that with that loop the background workers never complete where without it they normally would.  I think I can hook something into the on window closing event to check the queue count then close if it's 0 and abort otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you absolutely have to use BackgroundWorker? .NET 4 introduces the `Task` API (aka Task Parallel Library or TPL in short): you can start several tasks and use `Task.WhenAll` to provide a continuation that only executes when all tasks are finished:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myTasks = new List<Task<BitmapImage>>();
        // Task<T>.Factory.StartNew starts the given method on a Thread Pool thread
        myTasks.Add(Task<BitmapImage>.Factory.StartNew(LoadPicture1));
        myTasks.Add(Task<BitmapImage>.Factory.StartNew(LoadPicture2));

        // The important part: Task.WhenAll waits asynchronously until all tasks
        // in the collection finished sucessfully. Only then, the lambda that is
        // given to the ContinueWith method is executed. The UI thread does not block
        // in this case.
        Task.WhenAll(myTasks)
            .ContinueWith(task =>
                          {
                              foreach (var bitmapImage in task.Result)
                              {
                                  var image = new Image { Source = bitmapImage };
                                  ImageStackPanel.Children.Add(image);
                              }
                          },
                          TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }

    private BitmapImage LoadPicture1()
    {
        return LoadImageFile("Picture1.jpg");
    }

    private BitmapImage LoadPicture2()
    {
        // Simulate that this loading process takes a little bit longer
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return LoadImageFile("Picture2.jpg");
    }

    private BitmapImage LoadImageFile(string path)
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = fileStream;
            bitmapImage.EndInit();
            bitmapImage.Freeze();
            return bitmapImage;
        }
    }
}
```

You even can use async await if you program against .NET 4.5 (but I doubt that you use this version of .NET because you provided the .NET 4.0 tag in your question). Anyway, in case you want to stick to several BackgroundWorker objects, I would encapsulate all of them in a class and register to the Completed events of them. If all of them raised this event, then I would raise another event that tells all of them have completed.

You can learn more about the TPL here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx

You can download the whole example that I created here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14810011/LoadSeveralItemsWithTasks.zip

Comment: I was just using a queue setup, since I wanted each task to execute serially e.g. LoadPicture2 would only start once LoadPicture1 had finished.  In this example I would assume it's possible LoadPicture2 finishes before LoadPicture1, or the other way around.

Comment: That‘s correct. Just use ContinueWith on a task to define what should happen when this task finishes. Also check out the second to last link in my answer to learn what is possible with the Task class (it‘s a lot).

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like that

```
while (myWorkerQueue.Queue.Count > 0) ;
```

Your while loop is taking so much ressource that there is no more for your background threads. It appears blocked.

If you want to keep your while loop (which I don't advise), at least put a sleep in so your background threads can work:

```
while (myWorkerQueue.Queue.Count > 0)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

The easiest solution as you said in your comments is to hook the closing event and abort it if myWorkerQueue.Queue.Count > 0.

A more elegant solution is to create a modal form with a progress bar, show it when the form is closing and if myWorkerQueue.Queue.Count > 0, the progress bar would progress as the remaining background worker finish...